# How do I get window.location.reload(true) to only reload the correct page?

Tags: reactjs, page-refresh, window.location

In my react app I have the following code on all my pages except two of them

```
componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }, 300000);
}
```

However, the pages that the code is not on still reload unless I refresh those pages when I go on them. Why does that happen and how do I get those pages to not reload without refreshing them?

The window.location.hash property of the two pages are '#/credit-request' and '#/support-ticket' and I have also tried adding the following code to the pages instead but get the same result

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (window.location.hash != '#/credit-request' && window.location.hash != '#/support-ticket') {
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }, 300000);
    }
}
```

I also tried doing this in the html page by adding the following script in the body tag but still got the same result

```
<script>
    if (location.hash != '#/credit-request' && location.hash != '#/support-ticket') {
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }, 300000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do `clearInterval` after you `unmount` the component (i.e. go to different page). If you don't do it then the setInterval keeps running even if you navigate away from your component.

**Fix**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  intervalId = null;
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => window.location.reload(true), 30000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
}
...
```